# Why does my directory take a lot of space on disk when the files in it are small?

Tags: filesystems

```
root@VimLaTeX:/var/www/html/HandicraftStore/Web# du -h
76K ./font-awesome-4.7.0/css
128K    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/scss
128K    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/less
1.1M    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts
1.4M    ./font-awesome-4.7.0
28G .

root@VimLaTeX:/var/www/html/HandicraftStore/Web# ls
addToCart.php          checkout.php          jquery-3.3.1.js      productDetails.css  signupSuccessful.html
auctionDetails.php     cow.jpeg              jquery-3.3.1.min.js  productDetails.php  style.css
auction.php            database.php          long_poller.html     README.md           takeBid.php
bootstrap.min.css      delete.html           msgsrv.php           removeToCart.php    test1.html
bootstrap.min.js       delete.php            navbar.html          search.php          test.php
carousel.html          font-awesome-4.7.0    newnavbar.php        signinnavbar.html   typeChange.php
carousel.php           font-awesome.min.css  page1.php            signIn.php          updateAuctionDetails.php
cart_modal_porton.php  footer.html           page2.php            signOut.php
cart.php               insertLike.php        popper.min.js        signUp.php
```

There only one directory `font-awesome-4.7.0` under `Web` rest are files with KB sized. I don't understand why the `Web` directory grab `28GB`. There `HandicraftStore` contains a `.git` folder.

**Edit 1**

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

[image: image 6]

Comment: use `sudo baobab`, should give you the right anwser. (baobab is a gui program for analyzing disk space usage)

Comment: This question has been mentioned on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367525).

Comment: I'd like to see the output of `ls -ldh` from the `Web` directory.  If a dir takes 29.5GB but all its contents take less than a total of 1GB, then perhaps the dir itself is using the space.  Not sure what would cause that.

Comment: Also note that there may be hidden files. Check with `ls -la`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `du -sh * | sort -h` rather than `du -h`. The former checks all files and directories in the current directory; the latter checks only directories. However, baobob is the fun answer (thanks @ArminŠupuk )

If the bulk of the space is in a directory, cd to that directory and repeat, until you find where most of the space is taken.

To include hidden files (filenames beginning with `.`), use

```
du -sh $(ls -a) | sort -h
```